# TextEdit and listview in One page android

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have a listView in one page and I want to add fragment TextView in top of my page,

would you please let me know how should i implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you done? Please post some code or image of how you want it to be.

Comment: What have you tried? This is super easy and there are many many many tutorials about this.

Comment: I think you dont need another fragment for it, just add an editText on top of your listview inside your layout.

Comment: @zozelfelfo I cannot do that since I use this listview in other layout

Comment: No matter how is your layout, you will always be able to add another view inside a layout, just use another linearlayout or relativelayout.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a ListFragment, then what you need to do is the following:

1.) properly implement and override the onCreateView() function, for example like this:

```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   savedInstanceState)
   {
      ArrayAdapter<MyClass> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyClass>(inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myClassArray);
      //override toString() function to provide the string for ArrayAdapter if not using custom adapter
      setListAdapter(adapter);
      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listfragmentlayout, container, false);
   }
```

2.) specify the ListFragment's layout file in XML, in this case fragment_listfragmentlayout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/listfragment_textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/listfragment_yourtext" />

  <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/listfragment_textview" >
  </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This should work.